# Colorbar scale wrong on Octave

Tags: plot, octave, scatter-plot, colorbar, scatter

I try to create a graph in which there is a line with colour based on a third variable.
To do that, I'm using scatter plot.
When I add colorbar to this plot, the data range reported on the colorbar vary from zero to max value.
This is wrong, the data don't start from zero, and so the color visualized on the graph are wrong.
This is my code:

```
load data;
figure(1);
plot(brd_1(:,1), brd_1(:,2), "color", "k");
hold;
axis([x_range(1), x_range(2), y_range(1), y_range(2)], "equal", "off");
plot(brd_2(:,1), brd_2(:,2), "color", "k");
colormap("viridis");
scatter(pnt_rl(:,1), pnt_rl(:,2), 8, v*3.6, "filled");
colorbar("EastOutside");
title("Speed [km/h]");
```

Here there is the link of the file "data" needed to try this code:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Av6EBKUGP49_gt1twhMuRsZ1PyVtrw?e=Mgat0d

Comment: EDIT: I try to use caxis([min, max]), but if I save min and max in a variable, don't work. If I write manually the number, like caxis([50, 200]), then works. But I cannot write manually the numbers, and I don't understand why don't works using as variable

Answer (score 0):

I also had a wrong scale for scatter3. For me worked the following:
caxis([floor(vmin), ceil(vmax)]).
It seems integers are needed here.

This also worked: caxis([ single(min(v(:))), single(max(v(:)))])